# SPA 404 on Refresh: Go+React App on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, go, heroku, react-router

I'm seeing an issue on Heroku that I'm not having trouble with locally. I've seen various articles and other SO posts that address this issue, and I've got an understanding that it has something to do with properly configuring the `static.json` file in my app in order for heroku to properly handle front end react routing, but I'm having some real trouble resolving this.

- I'm using the following buildpacks and confirmed they're installed via the Heroku Dashboard > Settings:
- `https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku-community/static.tgz`
- `https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack`
- Using a `gin-gonic` server and serving up `./web` to serve the frontend as specified by my `.Dockerfile`
- I have the following static.json:

```
{
    "root": "build/",
    "routes": {
        "/**": "index.html"
    },
    "clean_urls": false,
    "https_only": true,
    "headers": {
        "/**": {
        "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31557600"
        }
    }
}
```

- My project structure is as follows:

```
/app
- /main.go
- /server
-- /server package .go files...
- /client
-- /public
-- /src
-- /remaining react related files and assets...
```

I have tried having the `static.json` file in the app root, as well as in the `client` dir to no avail. Still seeing 404s if I refresh on or navigate from an external site to anything but the homepage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, none of the static.json solutions that I found while researching this issue seemed to work. From what I gather this appears to be a known issue with react routing and/or Heroku.

That being said, if this is helpful for anyone else that comes across this issue, this is how I addressed it:

1. Set up a NotFound handler on the server:

   All this NotFound handler do is serve up your index.html file ***allowing your SPA framework to handle the routing itself (making the determination if valid or truly not found).***

   I achieved this in go/gin-gonic by:

   ```
   e := gin.New()
   // gin engine set up...

   e.NoRoute(func(ctx *gin.Context){
       ctx.File("./web")
   })
   ```

   Reason being - when you hit your app normally (via the base url) you're app will serve up index.html, and then and subsequent clicks from within the app are handled via the SPA routing. But if you navigate to any other route ***directly*** (i.e. manually going to `https://<your domain>.com/foo` in the address bar) You will be bypassing the SPA routing and going directly to the server. This case is also achieved by simply refreshing any page other than the homepage as well.

   So by serving up the index.html when you hit a not found on the server you are ***re-enabling the SPA framework to work its magic and serve up that route*** if its valid which is what we want, but also be able to handle the 404 by...
2. Wiring up a NotFound component in the React App:

   I achieved this in React by making a simple component and wiring up a Route to consume it by registering it to path="*" as a catch all after defining all other routes:

   ```
   <Router basename="/">
       <Route exact path="/foo">
           <FooView />
       </Route>
       <Route exact path="/">
           <HomeView />
       </Route>
       <Route path="*">
           <NotFoundView />
       </Route>
   </Router>
   ```